# How to bind focusOut event to knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind focusout event to my knockout js. here is the example:

```
<div class="form">
    <label>
        Country:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="countryName" name="countryId._autocomplete" data-bind="value: countryName,event: { blur: onBlurCountryEvent }" />
</div>

<div class="form" data-bind="visible: onBlurCountryEvent">
    <label>
       Time zone:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="timeZoneName" name="timeZoneId._autocomplete" data-bind="value: timeZoneName" />
</div>
```

and this is my knockoutjs:

```
define(['viewmodels/shell', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/services/logger', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'common', 'jqueryform', 'toastr', 'kovalidationconfig'],
    function (shell, system, logger, router, ko, common, jqueryform, toastr, kvc) {
        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            logger: logger,
            shell: shell,
            countryId: ko.observable(),
            countryName: ko.observable(),
            timeZoneName: ko.observable(),
            timeZoneId: ko.observable(),
            timeZoneVisibility: timeZoneVisibility,
            bindingComplete: function (view) {
                bindFindCountryEvent(view);
                bindFindTimeZoneEvent(view);
            }
        };

          vm.onBlurCountryEvent = function () {
            var countryVal = $('#countryName').val();
            if (countryVal != undefined && countryVal != null && countryVal != '') {
                console.log("trueee");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                console.log("falseee");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function bindFindCountryEvent(view) {
            jQuery("#countryName", view).typeahead(
                ...
        }
        function bindFindTimeZoneEvent(view) {
            jQuery("#timeZoneName", view).typeahead(
                ...
        }
        
        function activate(id) {
            shell.isLoading(true);
            ...

                shell.isLoading(false);
            });

            return true;
        }
         vm.save = function () {
           ...
        };
    });
```

So, as you can see, I want to have some event and binded function, when I do onBlur from my field country, to check, and to preview timezone field if there any selected country from dropdown search.
Also, if user skips the country, timezone filed should remain `visible:false`

the event works, and I can see in my console true/false values.
However, my field of timeZone is intact. No matter if this country field is empty or non-empty, the fields is visible always.
If I put `visible:false` (hardcoded value), it works.

Should I need to bind that function `vm.onBlurCountryEvent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the function `onBlurCountryEvent` is not an observable, so knockout is not checking for changes.  I would suggest adding a `isTimezoneVisible : ko.observable(false)` to your view model then set the `isTimeZoneVisible in the onBlurCountryEvent`.
In your view set the visible binding to isTimeZoneVisible.  Something like the following

```js
var vm = {
  countryId: ko.observable(),
  countryName: ko.observable(),
  timeZoneName: ko.observable(),
  timeZoneId: ko.observable(),
  isTimeZoneVisible: ko.observable(false), //new property
  bindingComplete: function(view) {
    bindFindCountryEvent(view);
    bindFindTimeZoneEvent(view);
  }
};

vm.onBlurCountryEvent = function() {
  var countryVal = $('#countryName').val();
  if (countryVal != undefined && countryVal != null && countryVal != '') {
    console.log("trueee");
    vm.isTimeZoneVisible(true); //set property
  } else {
    console.log("falseee");
    vm.isTimeZoneVisible(false); //set property
  }
}

function bindFindCountryEvent(view) {

}

function bindFindTimeZoneEvent(view) {

}


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <label>
        Country:
    </label>
  <input type="text" id="countryName" name="countryId._autocomplete" data-bind="value: countryName,event: { blur: onBlurCountryEvent }" />
</div>

<div class="form" data-bind="visible: isTimeZoneVisible">
  <label>
       Time zone:
    </label>
  <input type="text" id="timeZoneName" name="timeZoneId._autocomplete" data-bind="value: timeZoneName" />
</div>
```